# How can I add an progressbar to my canvas without xml?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-progressbar

this is my code for drawing text.

```
public void drawText(Canvas canvas)
{



    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
    canvas.drawText("DISTANCE: " + (player.getScore()) + " M", 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
    canvas.drawText("BEST: " + HighScore + " M", WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);



    if(!player.getPlaying()&&newGameCreated&&reset)
    {

        Bitmap b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coollogo);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b2, WIDTH/2 - 440, HEIGHT/2 - 360, paint);



        canvas.drawRect(380, 380,630,465 , paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b1, WIDTH/2 - 260, HEIGHT/2 + 20, paint);




    }

}
```

i now have this:
[image]

I want it like this:

[image]

I want a progressbar on that place, so you can level up in game.
No Loadingbar, just a progressbar so you can see how far you are in leveling up!
Can someone make this for me or how do i do this??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
animator= ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);

        // It will take 5000ms for the animator to go from 0 to 1
        animator.setDuration(5000);

        // Callback that executes on animation steps.
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                animationValue=((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();

                if(animationValue<=1.0 && animationValue>0.0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onAnimationUpdate: .... " + animationValue);
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        });
```

To draw progress using animationValue

```
canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth()*animationValue,getWidth()/8,mBackgroundBorder);
```

Comment: in which way? in the form of a progressbar? or just text?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
```

To show the progressbar write `progressbar.show();` 
and for hide write `progressbar.dismiss();`

Eg:-

```
public void drawText(Canvas canvas)
{

ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);
progressBar.show();
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(30);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
canvas.drawText("DISTANCE: " + (player.getScore()) + " M", 10, HEIGHT - 10, paint);
canvas.drawText("BEST: " + HighScore + " M", WIDTH - 215, HEIGHT - 10, paint);



if(!player.getPlaying()&&newGameCreated&&reset)
{

    Bitmap b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coollogo);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b2, WIDTH/2 - 440, HEIGHT/2 - 360, paint);



    canvas.drawRect(380, 380,630,465 , paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b1, WIDTH/2 - 260, HEIGHT/2 + 20, paint);




}

}
```

Comment: It does not work if i copy your code and paste it on my code.

Comment: may be because you have written .show() and .Dismiss() methods continuously don't write `progressbar.dismiss()`

Comment: it gives an error when i call   progressbar.show();

Comment: where have you initialised the ProgressBar..?

Comment: `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` use this to show

Comment: what happened..!!